# Operaciones básicas con php dentro de un html

Tags: php, html

soy nuevo en html y quisiera saber si es posible realizar operaciones con php dentro de un archivo html, pero sin utilizar un servidor local. Es decir, abrir el archivo html en el navegador, ingresar los valores en un input, que en el mismo archivo haya un  y me retorne el resultado en la misma u otra página. No sé si será posible. Mando el código en cuestión:

```
    <div class="principal contenedor">
    <article>
        <h2 class="titulo"> Movimiento rectilíneo uniforme </h2>
        <br>
        <p> Cálculo de la distancia </p>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <table> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <input  size="14" type="number" name="tiempomru" placeholder="Tiempo [s]" maxlength="50" required>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <b>
                        <input  size="14" type="number" name="velocidadmru" placeholder="Velocidad [m/s]" maxlength="50" required>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <div class="botonera">
                <input type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="Atrás">
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Calcular">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            $t = $_POST["tiempomru"];
            $v = $_POST["velocidadmru"];
            $d = $t*$v;
            echo "La distancia recorrida es de".$d."metros";
        ?>
    </article>
```

Supongo que o bien habrá un error en el código, o que lo que estoy tratando de hacer no se puede. Agradezco la ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: No  puedes directamente, podrías hacerlo con javascript. El servidor procesa el código en php para dar una salida en html

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me podrías dar un ejemplo para este caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ejemplo de hacerlo con javascript puede ser de la siguiente manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="principal contenedor">
    <article>
        <h2 class="titulo"> Movimiento rectil&iacute;neo uniforme </h2>
        <br>
        <p> C&aacute;lculo de la distancia </p>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <table> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <input id="tiempo" size="14" type="number" name="tiempomru" placeholder="Tiempo [s]" maxlength="50" required>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <b>
                        <input id="velocidad" size="14" type="number" name="velocidadmru" placeholder="Velocidad [m/s]" maxlength="50" required>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <div class="botonera">
                <input type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="Atr&aacute;s">
                <input id="calcular" type="button" name="enviar" value="Calcular">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calcular()
            {
                t = document.getElementById('tiempo').value;
                v = document.getElementById('velocidad').value;
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "La distancia recorrida es de "+ (t*v) +" mts";

            }
            document.getElementById('calcular').addEventListener("click", calcular);
        </script>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```